# What class to import from JSoup library to be able to use the "getElement" classes

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to find elements in an html page using Jsoup and I need to use the `getElementsByAttributeValue` class along with all the `getElement` classes.

The error showing in netbeans 8.0 is:

> "cant find symbol"

so I suppose I haven't import the proper class in the head of the program. So what do I have to "import" to be able to use the `getElement` classes or if the problem is not in the "import" thing whats going on?

I can not use any of `getElement` by the way (is not only `getElementsByAttributeValue`) and I am using other classes of Jsoup like select with no problem.

Comment: I am srry. I have to correct something important in the last question. getElementsByAttributeValue is a method no a class. The error says it can not find the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**getElementsByAttributeValue** is the method of the class **org.jsoup.nodes.Element** so if you have an object of this class you should be able to access the method.

Comment: Hello man thanks for the answer, thing is i already imported that class like this: ** import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;** . Still getting the no find symbol error. I started a new proyect and same is happening this time with: **import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;** Then the line: **XWPFWordExtractor ext = new WordExtractor(fs.getRoot());** get the same error. Is like the import class is no being reconaigze or something like that, any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: `package sectors;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

iimport org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.extractor.XWPFWordExtractor;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;


public class TomaDatos  {
 
public void nombre()throws IOException{

    String ubic = "D:\\Varios\\Trabajo\\Bolsa\\sectorpp.docx";
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(ubic));
    XWPFWordExtractor ext = new WordExtractor(file);
}
  
}`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, some how i solved the problem with this code:

```
`package sectors;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.extractor.XWPFWordExtractor;

public class TomaDatos  {

public void nombre()throws IOException{


    String ubic = "D:\\Varios\\Trabajo\\Bolsa\\sectorpp.docx";

    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(ubic));

    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(file);   
    XWPFWordExtractor ex = new XWPFWordExtractor(doc);

}


}`
```

I really don´t know where exactly the problem was. The only important change was add XWPF after the "new" sentence here: `XWPFWordExtractor ex = new XWPFWordExtractor(doc);` But beleave me i tried that before and didnt work. Maybe is a problem with netbeans. I am sorry that i can not find the error, anyway, hope this work for someone....